My queries have an error near ALL
Here's my query:
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 2500 *
   FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use]
   WHERE phase = 'Primary'
     AND school_category = 'Maintained'
     AND Role IN ('headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'assistant headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'school business manager / bursar')
     AND segment NOT IN ('Special schools','Very small schools','PRUs','')
     
   ORDER BY NEWID()
   
) AS PrimaryMaintained

UNION ALL
-- Get 2,500 primary academies
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 2500 *
   FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use]
   WHERE phase = 'Primary'
     AND school_category = 'Academy'
     AND Role IN ('headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'assistant headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'school business manager / bursar')
     AND segment NOT IN ('Special schools','Very small schools','PRUs','')
   ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS PrimaryAcademies

UNION ALL

-- Get 500 secondary maintained schools
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 500 *
   FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use]
   WHERE phase = 'Secondary'
     AND school_category = 'Maintained'
     AND Role IN ('headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'assistant headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'school business manager / bursar')
     AND segment NOT IN ('Special schools','Very small schools','PRUs','')
   ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS SecondaryMaintained

UNION ALL

-- Get 500 secondary academies
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 500 *
   FROM CM_Engagement_2024_use
   WHERE phase = 'Secondary'
     AND school_category = 'Academy'
     AND Role IN ('headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'assistant headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'school business manager / bursar')
     AND segment NOT IN ('Special schools','Very small schools','PRUs','')
   ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS SecondaryAcademies

It has a Syntax error near All and I don't know what that is. Can someone please help?

Double-dash comments aren't allowed in SFMC Query Activities.  Just swap out -- for /* comment here */.

Once you fix the comment notation, I think you'll have issues combining the unions and the ordering.
You might consider numbering all of the rows randomly with a windowing function and moving your volume criteria to the where clause like this:
select
  x.phase
, x.school_category
, x.Role
, x.segment
, x.[group]
, x.rowNumber
from (

  SELECT 
    e.phase
  , e.school_category
  , e.Role
  , e.segment
  , 'Primary Maintained' as [group]
  , row_number() over (order by newid()) as rowNumber
  FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use] as e
  WHERE 1=1
  AND e.phase = 'Primary'
  AND e.school_category = 'Maintained'

  union

  SELECT
    e.phase
  , e.school_category
  , e.Role
  , e.segment
  , 'Primary Academy' as [group]
  , row_number() over (order by newid()) as rowNumber
  FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use] as e
  WHERE 1=1
  AND e.phase = 'Primary'
  AND e.school_category = 'Academy'

  union

  SELECT
    e.phase
  , e.school_category
  , e.Role
  , e.segment
  , 'Secondary Maintained' as [group]
  , row_number() over (order by newid()) as rowNumber
  FROM [CM_Engagement_2024_use] as e
  WHERE 1=1
  AND e.phase = 'Secondary'
  AND e.school_category = 'Maintained'

  union 

  SELECT
    e.phase
  , e.school_category
  , e.Role
  , e.segment
  , 'Secondary Academy' as [group]
  , row_number() over (order by newid()) as rowNumber
  FROM CM_Engagement_2024_use as e
  WHERE 1=1
  and e.phase = 'Secondary'
  AND e.school_category = 'Academy'

) as x
where 1=1
AND x.Role IN ('headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'assistant headteacher', 'deputy headteacher', 'school business manager / bursar')
AND x.segment NOT IN ('Special schools','Very small schools','PRUs','')
and (
      (x.[group] = 'Primary Maintained' and x.rowNumber <= 3)
      or (x.[group] = 'Primary Academy' and x.rowNumber <= 3)
      or (x.[group] = 'Secondary Maintained' and x.rowNumber <= 1)
      or (x.[group] = 'Secondary Academy' and x.rowNumber <= 1)
)




phase
school_category
Role
segment
group
rowNumber




Primary
Academy
headteacher
large school
Primary Academy
1


Primary
Academy
headteacher
large school
Primary Academy
2


Primary
Academy
headteacher
large school
Primary Academy
3


Primary
Maintained
headteacher
large school
Primary Maintained
1


Primary
Maintained
headteacher
large school
Primary Maintained
2


Primary
Maintained
headteacher
large school
Primary Maintained
3


Secondary
Academy
headteacher
large school
Secondary Academy
1


Secondary
Maintained
headteacher
large school
Secondary Maintained
1



Try it yourself: fiddle
NOTE: I removed the select * and included the actual field names.  SFMC caches the column names with the Query Activities, which will cause problems if your source or target data extension schemas change.  Plus, wildcards and unions don't work nicely together.

Amazing! I actually fixed it simply by removing the comment notations. But your suggestions are very good. I will apply them next time. Thank you for helping!
